# Latency sometimes encounter when queryForList

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, hikaricp

I have a java spring boot service which provides data for other micro-services. In this java service, I have some HikariCP JDBC connection pools. The configuration basically follows the same standard as follows:

```
jdbcUrl: jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx:xxx:xxx
username: xxx
password: xxx
driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
poolName: xxx
maximumPoolSize: 100
minimumIdle: 10
idleTimeout: 7200000
connectionTimeout: 1800000
```

Everything looks fine and I could get data from the database successfully by the implementation below:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> data = jdbc.queryForList(query);
```

However, I found out that sometimes there is much latency when it executes the above line of code. For example, the normal time of the above takes only 3 seconds but sometimes it takes 20 or 30 seconds. I checked the database monitoring tool, it shows the query spent time only is 2/3 seconds. I am not sure whether the latency was from getting the database connection, or elsewhere. As stated in the config, we have minimumIdle size as 10 which means we should have a pool size of 10 connections available. What is the root cause of these latencies?

Comment: How many records are being retrieved? What is the load of the database? What is the load of the machine running the microservice? There are too many factors that affect the performance.

Comment: Only a few hundred of records are being retrieved. The total number of rows are not a lot but only around 30,000. The load of the machine running the microservice is also low on both CPU and memory.